# Elasticsearch lucene, understand code path for search

Tags: debugging, elasticsearch, lucene

I want to understand how each of the lucene index files (nvd,dvd,tim,doc.. mainly these four) are used in ES query. 
E.g. say my index has ten docs and i am doing a aggregation query. I would like to understand how ES/Lucene performs access to these four files for a single query.

I am trying to see if I can make some optimization in my system which is mostly a disk heavy system to speed up query performance.
I looked at ES code and understand that the QueryPhase is the most expensive and it seems to be doing a lot of randomn access to disk for the log oriented data I have.

I want to now dive deeper on lucene level as well and possibly debug code and see in action. Lucene code has zero log messages for IndexReader related classes. Also debugging lucene code directly seems unhelpful since the unittest don't create indexes with tim, doc, nvd, dvd files

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, ES don't do much on search details, if your want optimize search, my experience is optimize your data layout, here is some important lucene files description:

(see http://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene70/package-summary.html#package.description):

1. Term Index(.tip) **# ON MEMORY**.
2. Term Dictionary(.tim) **# ON DISK**.
3. Frequencies(.doc) **# ON DISK**.
4. Per-Document Values(.dvd, .dvm), very useful on aggregation. **# ON DISK**.
5. Field Index(.fdx) **# ON MEMORY**.
6. Field Data(.fdt), finally data fetch from disk in here. **# ON DISK**.

And there are some point can optmize performance:

1. trying use small date type, for example: INTEGER or LONG values instead of STRING.
2. CLOSE DocValues on unnecessary field, at the same time open DocValues on that filed which your want to sort/aggregation.
3. just incluse necessasy field on source like "_source": { "includes": ["some_necessasy_field"]}.
4. only index field that your need using ES defined mappings.
5. split your data on multi index.
6. add SSD.